# Rotas Filhas, Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um component, onde o mesmo recebe apenas um parâmetro em sua rota, desta forma abaixo:

```html
{path: ':modelo', component: BaseNumerica,
```

Esse component por sua  vez, possui 3 rotas filhas, descritas da seguinte maneira:

```html
{path: ':modelo', component: BaseNumerica, 
        children:  [
            {path: '', redirectTo: 'teste1', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'teste1', component: Personal},
            {path: 'teste2', component: Dealers},
            {path: 'teste3', component: Agendamento}
        ]},
```

Estou com dificuldade de acessar a rota 'teste2', pelo component  da rota 'teste1', ou seja, no meu component teste1.html tenho a seguinte chamada:

```html
[routerLink]="['teste2']"
```

e é apresentado o seguinte erro:

```html
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'modelo/teste1/teste2'
```

Esse erro não acontece se eu faço o mesmo botão no component 'BaseNumerica'. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Guilherme isso acontece por que passando apenas teste2 ele compreende que você pretende acessar um nível acima do atual.

Por isso de BaseNumerica você acessa o teste2 sem problemas passando apenas ele.

Para acessar a partir do teste1 é preciso passar o caminho completo neste caso.

['/:modelo/teste2'] no link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guilherme isso acontece por que passando apenas teste2 ele compreende que você pretende acessar um nível acima do atual. Por isso de BaseNumerica você acessa o teste2 sem problemas passando apenas ele. Para acessar a partir do teste1 é preciso passar o caminho completo neste caso. `['/:Tmodelo/teste2']` no link

Comment: Entendi. Porém fiz o teste aqui e é apresentado esse erro 'Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ':Tmodelo/teste2''

Comment: o :Tmodelo não deveria ser substituido por `/modelo` e deoius completado com o `/teste2/` somente?
Tecnicamente quando tu tava no teste1 ele direcionou para `modelo/teste1/teste2` , e se o teste1 e teste2 estão no mesmo nível acho que seria `/modelo/teste2/`

Comment: Ok. funcionou rs, value!

Esse modelo é um parâmetro, eu consigo obter a string desse parâmetro?

Comment: Podemos pegar utilizando o SNAPSHOT:          

snapshot.parent.params['modelo']

Comment: Valeu foi nada. :)